# Python includes files on Lion?

Tags: python, macos, osx-lion

Where have been includes files of python in lion ?
Usually it was located at "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6" but there is only one files in there : "pyconfig.h"

Is it the same on your system ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On OS X 10.7, the `include` files for the Apple-supplied Pythons are linked into the locations within `/System/Library/Frameworks` when you install `Xcode 4`.  You will find also find them in the `/Developer/SDKs` included with `Xcode`, for example:

```
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7
```

By the way, the canonical way to find the location of Python's `include` files is to use the `python-config` command associated with the Python instance you are using:

```
$ /usr/bin/python2.7-config --include
-I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7
```

UPDATE:  I initially answered that the `include` files were only found in the SDK location.  But I then remembered that, due to a nasty bug, I had had to reinstall 10.7 Lion on the same partition and by doing so that wiped out the links that the initial `Xcode 4` install had made.  After also re-installing `Xcode 4` everything was as it should be. Something to keep in mind if you have to reinstall Lion.

Answer (score 1):

Do this

```
import sys
sys.path
```

It will show you where the library files are.  Something like this

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages

From the site-packages, go up three directory levels and down into `include`  (`../../../include/python2.6`).  You'll find things here:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6

Note.  No `/System`

Comment: While your technique is OK, the path you cite is not valid for the Apple-supplied Pythons in OS X.  Those *are* in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`.  The files in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework` are from a third-party Python framework install, such as the python.org OS X installers or from your own build from source.